# Question from Bott and Tu's Differential Forms book

Tags: differential-forms

On page 6 of the introduction, they state

> Indeed consider the de Rham theory of $\mathbb{R}^1$ with compactly supported forms. Clearly the only function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the zero function.

I just started reading about this, so I bet I am missing something. What about bump functions like the ones described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function? Don't they contain a compactly supported function defined on the real line?

Comment: Can you take a photo of that Page and post here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

They mean only function that is **locally constant function with compact support** is the zero function.